# Make array sorted using given operations

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a list of M numbers marked 1 to M. Also we are given with Q operations of type : X Y

Each operation means we can simply change number with value X to number with value Y or vice-verse . Also the operations are transitive. It means If X->Y and Y->Z then X can be changed to Z also.

Now we are given a sequence of N numbers and we need to make it sorted that is in increasing order (It may not be strictly increasing) by modifying minimum number of numbers. If not possible tell its not possible by returning -1.

**Example :** Suppose we have 3 numbers(=M) and 3 operations(=Q) as follow :

```
1 2
2 3
1 3
```

and Let N=3 with array to be modified as [3,2,1] then answer is 2 (since we modify 2 numbers in array ) as it's possible to transform the first number to 1 and the last number to 2. The resulting array is [1,2,2] which is increasing.

But let M=3 and we have only one operation : 2 3 . Also let N=2 and array be [2,1] then its not possible to make it sorted because it can only be transformed to [2,1] or [3,1].

So how to solve this problem ? Please help

Its given that M can be at max 200 , so we can find which numbers we can reach from particular number. But am not able to solve it because N can be up to 200000. So how to maintain wheather array is sorted or not. I think DP can help but no clue yet.

Comment: Are the operations in Q commutative? Otherwise I don't follow your explanation. Also where are you getting N from? You are using both M and N in the example, but you never defined N in the problem description.

Comment: @KonsolLabapen Yeah they are commutative. I had defined N in problem statement. N is the number of elements in array to be modified and M are numbers available

Comment: @Asad Operation is simply replace a specific value with a specific other value and yes operations are transitive.Also we need not see count of operations.We need to make array sorted with changing minimum numbers in array

Comment: Can an operation only be used once?

Comment: @Asad Not necessary an operation can be used any number of times.It does not matter. We need to minimse the number of values in array that are to be modified to make it increasing

Comment: @Asad Is it clear now ? What am trying to ask ? Its like we are given a list of some numbers with there replacements and we need to find weather we can make an array in sorted order by applying those replacements

Comment: @Mrinal Yes, it is clear.

Comment: @Mrinal If you do a merge sort on a copy of the input, you should be able to identify all inversions in the array. Then for each inversion you can check if there is an operation available that corrects it. I'm not sure what the time complexity of the second step is, but the first is nlogn.

Comment: @Asad How to find inversions ? I know to count them though but say array was 3 2 1 after modifying it become 1 2 2 so which number to be replaced with which number is difficult task. Getting my point ?

Comment: @Mrinal You simply need to keep track of the original index of each element when doing your mergesort, and when you find an inversion and would normally count it, store the indices instead.

Comment: @Asad How it will help ? Am not getting you

Comment: Your examples are almost trivial. Do you have an example with a large N and Q greater than size 3? Also in your example are you aware that the answer can be `{3,2,1} => {1,1,1}`?

Comment: @KatedralPillon But numbers changed are still same

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an attempt to get answers for an ongoing contest.

Answer (score -1):

This is an explanation to use to create an algorithm.

First start by assembling all the Ys for a given X into a Map. Then assemble all the Xs for a given Y. So that you would end up with the data structure `Map<Key,Value>` as `Map<Integer,List<Integer>>`. So for instance if Q is

```
1  2
2  3
1  3
4  3
```

Then for X=1 you would have a Map entry as `<1,{2,3}>`. So the complete mapping would be

```
<1,{2,3}>
<2,{1,3}>
<4,{3}>
<3,{1,2,4}>
```

Note that since Q is a commutative set of operations, we don't need to have two keys for 2 although two appears as both X and Y. So I hope you were able to follow so far, because the entire algorithm rests on this mapping. Then the algorithm.

```java
package algorithm;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class SortArray {

    /**
     * Given an array and a set of commutative and transitive exchanges, sort the array in
     * increasing order. return the number of operations it took to sort the array.
     * 
     * @param input
     * @param operations
     * @return
     */
    static int sortArray(int[] input, int[][] operations) {
        int ops = 0;
        Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = flattenOperations(operations);
        int min = smallestElement(operations);
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            ops += minimize(i, input, min, map);
        }

        if (isSortedAscending(input)) {
            return ops;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }

    }

    /**
     * the given array is a set of {X,Y} pairs as in {{X0,Y0},{X1,Y1},...}.
     * This method assembles all the Xs for a given Y and then all the Ys for a given X.
     * This is okay because the operations are commutative.
     * 
     * @param operations
     * @return
     */
    static private Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> flattenOperations(int[][] operations) {
        Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>();
        // add Ys for X keys
        for (int[] operation : operations) {
            Set<Integer> s = map.get(operation[0]);
            if (s == null) {
                s = new TreeSet<Integer>();
                s.add(operation[1]);
                map.put(operation[0], s);
            } else {
                s.add(operation[1]);
            }
        }

        for (int[] operation : operations) {
            Set<Integer> s = map.get(operation[1]);
            if (s == null) {
                s = new HashSet<Integer>();
                s.add(operation[0]);
                map.put(operation[1], s);
            } else {
                s.add(operation[0]);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    static private int smallestElement(int[][] operations) {
        int min = Math.min(operations[0][0], operations[0][1]);
        for (int i = 1; i < operations.length; i++) {
            int tmpMin = Math.min(operations[i][0], operations[i][1]);
            min = Math.min(min, tmpMin);
        }
        return min;
    }

    /**
     * Replace the element at the given index i with the minimum value possible. The minimum value
     * possible is greater than or equal to min but less than the original value at input[i]. If
     * the operation was successful return the number of exchanges, else return 0. This is a
     * subroutine. It makes sense in the greater context. This may not end in a sorted array. But
     * the caller is responsible for checking for sorting at a later point.
     * 
     * 
     * @param i
     * @param input
     * @param min
     * @param map
     * @return
     */
    static private int minimize(int i, int[] input, int min, Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map) {
        int key = input[i];
        boolean done = false;
        int ops = 0;
        while (!done) {
            int tmp = findSmallestValueLessThanKeyButGreaterThanOrEqualToMin(key, min, map);
            if (-1 != tmp) {
                key = tmp;
                ops++;
            } else {
                done = true;
            }
        }
        input[i] = key;
        return ops;
    }

    /**
     * The lists are assumed to be pre-sorted in ascending order so that the smallest value is at
     * index 0.
     * 
     * @param key
     * @param min
     * @param map
     * @return
     */
    static private int findSmallestValueLessThanKeyButGreaterThanOrEqualToMin(int key, int min, Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map) {
        Set<Integer> set = map.get(key);
        if (null != set) {
            for (int el : set) {
                if (el < key && el >= min) {
                    return el;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    static private boolean isSortedAscending(int[] input) {
        for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (input[i - 1] > input[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // ====================================================================================
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // int[][] Q = { { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 1, 3 } };
        // int[] input = { 3, 2, 1 };
        int[][] Q = { { 2, 3 } };
        int[] input = { 2, 1 };

        int ops = sortArray(input, Q);
        System.out.println("Number of operations is " + ops);
        System.out.println("The new array is " + Arrays.toString(input));
    }
}
```

Comment: Few queries. Query 1: What is M array here in sort function ?

Comment: Also am not getting what you are trying to do in minimize function. above that I got almost all

Comment: I imagine you are given an array and a set of operations Q. I call the input array M.  If you want you can call it `input[]`

Comment: Now just explain a bit more of minimize function

Comment: I have edited to give you a bit more. But I have done 90% of the work for you. At this point, any more info would mean doing the remaining 10%.

Comment: What about case when its not possible ?

Comment: After the for loop you use an if-else statement. If it is sorted return ops else return -1.

Comment: If indeed this is homework that final comment is equivalent to spoon feeding.

Comment: @Konsol Labapen How are you ensuring the while(!done) loop does not rum infinte ?

Comment: @Konsol Labapen Almost got it but in map corresponding to which key are you searching for Smallest Value  Less Than Key But Greater Than Or Equal To Min

Comment: @Mrinal The key here is the current value. You walk through the array and at each location try to apply a sequence of swaps that will minimize the value of the current location yet also keep it higher than the last location.

Comment: @Mrinal Look, you have the map representing the operations. When you access the index in this map corresponding to the element you're currently sitting at, `M[i]`, you get a list of values you're allowed to replace it with. Out of these, find the minimum value such that it is less than the current value `M[i]` and greater than or equal to the minimum value already traversed, `min`.

Comment: @Asad I example quoted in answer aren't the vlaue of map shown wrong ? Because I think each one can go to other in mentioned example . I mean 1->{1,2,3,4} and similarly remaining three

Comment: @Konsol I'm not entirely sure about this, but this seems like a greedy algorithm wrt applying the operations. Wouldn't this mean that there could be an optimal path that isn't visited? E.g. if you're sitting at 7, your min so far is `1`, and your map has the operations `[7->{5,3}, 5->{1}]`, wouldn't the  algorithm go with the replacement `7->3` on the first iteration and possibly end up with an incorrect result? Maybe this needs to be addressed in the map creation?

Comment: @Asad Yeah thats also another point that i was going to ask. Please help me to build the whole algorithm..:/

Comment: @Mrinal Yes, the transitivity has not been taken into consideration in this answer. I think what you need to do is deal with transitivity during the creation of the map, so that you do in fact have `1->{1,2,3,4}` in the map. Then you can remove the while loop in `minimize`. Additionally, I think you need to set `min` to the final value you get after your replacement, rather than the original value `M[i]`.

Comment: @Asad ehh..Lots of confusion ..:(

Comment: Since now I have two confused readers instead of one, I will put up the whole answer by editing and then we can discuss some more after you guys run the code on your own machine.

Comment: @KonsolLabapen Thanks for putting that up, this is much clearer. Here is what I was talking about earlier: http://ideone.com/isqypy. The only thing I've changed is the main method, where I've put in the input I wanted to demonstrate. The algorithm arrives at the conclusion that there is no way to sort the input with the given operations, even though there is.

Comment: @Asad Awesome! If you find the corrections please make the edits. I will take a look.